# Calling user defined function in Insert command of Sqlite

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I have written a user defined function to calculate checksum for a given string. I need to insert the calculated hash value into the table. 
I used the following method

```
char msg[] = "Testing of the hash"
len = strlen(msg)
char *sql = "INSERT INTO TestHash (id,CheckSum) VALUES (?,hash(msg,len));"
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);
sqlite3_step(res)
```

but sqlite throws a error "failed to prepare insert sql statement:no such column:msg". 
What is the right way to call a UDF in insert command.

Platform:linux
Language:C
database:sqlite

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using a [parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) for the ID value.
Do the same for the other two values:

```
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO TestHash (id,CheckSum) VALUES (?,hash(?,?));"
/* error handling omitted */
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_int(res, 1, ...);
sqlite3_bind_text(res, 2, msg, len, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_int(res, 3, len);
rc = sqlite3_step(res);
```

If the ID value should be NULL (for an autoincremented value), you should not use a parameter for it.

Your hash function should not need the length parameter.

Comment: Both your method and Shadow's method work. which is better.

Comment: had problem with sqlite_binding_text ,was sending wrong column number for second parameter

Answer (score 1):

`msg` is a C program level variable. In the sql command you cannot reference a C variable, you have to insert its content into the sql statement as a string literal. The same applies to the `len` variable.

You basically need to generate the following string within your C program:

```
char *sql = "INSERT INTO TestHash (id,CheckSum) VALUES (?,hash('Testing of the hash',19));"
```